# Post to Facebook wall/feed using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

pulling my hair out over this one.

I'm writing a Facebook-connected web app that will ultimately post some arbitrary information to the walls of friends that are selected throughout the process.

I'm in the final stages now and was hoping that posting to the walls would be simple, but I've spent far too long trying to figure this out now so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm trying to post using ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/bbeckford/feed",
    data: {message: wallMessage, target_id: friendID, access_token: "<?= $cookie['access_token'] ?>", format: "json"},
    success: function(data) { alert(data); },
    dataType: "JSON"
});
```

But I just keep getting this error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph.facebook.com/bbeckford/feed. Origin http://www.secretsantasetup.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

I've done searches and one suggestion is to make a php proxy, is that a viable option? How would I go about doing that?

Am I approaching this completely wrong??

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
-Ben

**EDIT**
I want to do this in the background, ie user has selected 10 friends for example, then on submit the app will loop through each friend and post something on their wall. Is this possible?
Thanks!

**EDIT 2**
The test console at the bottom of the following page does exactly what I want to do, but there is no source code? - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go using javaScript SDK

**STEP 1**

At first, your application should obtain the permission for posting on user's wall or user's friends wall.

sample code from Facebook :  [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    if (response.perms) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
    } else {
      // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
    }
  } else {
    // user is not logged in
  }
}, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

publish_stream is required to post on user's or user's friends wall.

Line which one need to edit : **{perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'})**

To read more about other permissions : [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

**STEP 2**

Taken from facebook JavaScript SDK Pages and tweaked [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

```
   FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
     attachment: {
       name: 'Connect',
       caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
       description: (
         'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
         'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
         'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
       ),
       href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'
     },
     target_id: 'ENTER YOU FRIENDS IDS - more than one, seperate by commas',
     action_links: [
       { text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }
     ],
     user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }

 );
```

Line which one needs to edit or add : **target_id: 'ENTER YOU FRIENDS IDS - more than one, seperate by commas',**

:)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send ajax request to the another domain.

Just take [facebook JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and do whatever you want.

Comment: I've looked through that stuff and can't find a decent example, can I post to walls asynchronously using that method?

Comment: @bbeckford: Yes, you can post asynchronously. Here is a sample: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out but I still don't think that's what I'm looking for. I've edited my question to explain better.

Comment: @bbeckford: you can call REST methods via JS SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api

Comment: Thanks I figured it out from this eventually but sashtinathan has posted a full solution so I accepted that for the purpose of people searching

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where did I heard this, but:

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+therequestid+"/?callback=?&access_token="+access_token,{},
           function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                          //bla-bla
           }
       );
```

Should work, where you need to add "?callback=?" stuff. I do not know why did this work. But, as long as it works, I'll stay happy.

Comment: This relies on a JSONP callback, which is a common way for working around Same Origin browser security limits with AJAX. That said, this will only work for GET requests that return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the scope while authenticating the user, (if you haven't done so).

If you authenticated using WAMS, check this blog to set scopes http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2013/11/25/what-s-new-in-azure-mobile-services-1-6-4247.aspx